# Could not create service of type ChecksumService using BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService()

Tags: gradle

I am new in gradle and when I try to simple check gradle built in tasks, I get Build Failed error.

Can anybody explain what is wrong?

I only run 'gradle tasks' on cmd and get next error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
> Could not create service of type ChecksumService using BuildSessionScopeServices.createChecksumService().
   > Timeout waiting to lock checksums cache (M:\.gradle\checksums). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: unknown
     Our PID: 14372
     Owner Operation: unknown
     Our operation:
     Lock file: M:\.gradle\checksums\checksums.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
--scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I wonder if it's due to not being on the `C:/` drive, as mine is on a `G:/` drive being managed by Google Drive and I see yours is on an `M:/` drive.

Comment: I started a new project on the `C:/` drive on my Desktop and it seems to have worked. Perhaps that's it.

Answer (score 15):

`./gradlew --stop` as the error happens when gradle didn't close cleanly. Such as in: `Cannot lock checksums cache (/Users/.../StudioProjects/android/.gradle/7.4.2/checksums) as it has already been locked by this process.`

Comment: Thanks! that solved a similar issue for me

Answer (score 4):

This was a permissions issue for me.
I tried running a project on my Mac from my mounted Google Drive directory and got this error.

Moving the project to Documents worked.

Comment: Similar for me... project files inside WSL Ubuntu, could run Gradle from bash shell, but IntelliJ on Windows couldn't execute. Moved project out of WSL to C: and worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I forgot to stop the server in IntelliJ and once I did the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

**For Flutter users**

I faced this problem on Mac OS Monterey (M1 processor)

*I solved it in the following way*

1. Browse android/buil.gradle add or update gradle version to 7.1.2

```dart
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'. //---this
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

2. Update distributionUrl in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to 7.4

```dart
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

3. Navigate in the terminal to the android folder and run

```
cd android
```

despues

```
./gradlew --stop
```

4.Run flutter clean and flutter pub get

```
flutter clean
```

```
flutter pub get
```

5. Then run flutter run

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

1. Close my IDE
2. Go to my project directory
3. Search and delete all .lock files
4. Open the IDE, and try again

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem while building via terminal in WSL without me realizing that the Windows Intellij window I had opened was also building (typically Intellij will build by default when opening projects, or when switching branches, etc.). The building does take long and I did not notice. If that is your case, simply wait until the build is done or cancel it.

Answer (score -2):

Just restart your machine. it's a cache related error

Comment: Nope, doesn't work